# Reordering Multilevel Number in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nested, multi-level

DataTable columns selected from SQL as following:

| id | level_0 | level_1 | level_2 | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 114 | 1 | 0 | 0 | description 1 |
| 115 | 1 | 1 | 0 | description 2 |
| 116 | 1 | 1 | 1 | description 3 |
| 117 | 1 | 1 | 2 | description 4 |

and so on...

A list of multilevel number displayed in the user interface as following from datatable

```
1.0.0  description 1
1.1.0  description 2
1.1.1  description 3
1.1.2  description 4
1.1.3  description 5
1.2.0  description 6
1.2.1  description 7
1.2.2  description 8
1.2.3  description 9
1.2.4  description 10
1.3.0  description 11
1.3.1  description 12
2.0.0  description 13
2.1.0  description 14
2.2.0  description 15
3.0.0  description 16
3.1.0  description 17
... and so on
```

If the user deleting these items: 1.1.2, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, my current result will be:

```
1.0.0  description 1
1.1.0  description 2
1.1.1  description 3
1.1.3  description 5
1.2.0  description 6
1.2.1  description 7
1.2.3  description 9
1.2.4  description 10
1.3.0  description 11
1.3.1  description 12
3.0.0  description 16
3.1.0  description 17
```

Expected output:

```
1.0.0  description 1
1.1.0  description 2
1.1.1  description 3
1.1.2  description 5
1.2.0  description 6
1.2.1  description 7
1.2.2  description 9
1.2.3  description 10
1.3.0  description 11
1.3.1  description 12
2.0.0  description 16
2.1.0  description 17
```

May I know, how to write the code behind ASP.NET C# or VB.NET code to reordering my multi-level numbering after user deleted some wrong items, by updating my data table multilevel number to the correct one in the expected output?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `1.0.0` is deleted?

Comment: If delete 1.0.0 and 1.1.0, Expected output: 1.0.0 desc 3 1.1.0 desc 4 1.1.1 desc 5 1.1.2 desc 6 1.1.3 desc 7 1.2.0 desc 8 1.2.1 desc 9 1.2.2 desc 10 1.2.3 desc 11 1.2.4 desc 12 2.0.0 desc 13 2.1.0 desc 14 2.2.0 desc 15 3.0.0 desc 16 & etc

Comment: What happens if only `1.0.0` is deleted? What rule would map 1.1.0,1.1.1 => 1.0.0,1.1.0?

Comment: if `1.0.0` deleted, it would be 1.0.0, 1.1.0

Comment: Why is it 1.0.0,1.1.0 and not 1.0.0,1.0.1? Why wouldn't that mean next should be 1.2.0 instead of 1.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind being tied to having 3 levels in your code, you just need to setup a 3 level counter and then reset each level when the original level changes to renumber every item:

```
int level0 = 1, level1 = 0, level2 = 0;
var firstRow = dt.Rows[0];
int curLevel0 = firstRow.Field<int>("level_0"), curLevel1 = firstRow.Field<int>("level_1");
foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable()) {
    if (row.Field<int>("level_0") != curLevel0) {
        curLevel0 = row.Field<int>("level_0");
        curLevel1 = row.Field<int>("level_1");
        ++level0;
        level1 = 0;
        level2 = 0;
    }
    if (row.Field<int>("level_0") != level0)
        row["level_0"] = level0;

    if (row.Field<int>("level_1") != curLevel1) {
        curLevel1 = row.Field<int>("level_1");
        ++level1;
        level2 = 0;
    }
    if (row.Field<int>("level_1") != level1)
        row["level_1"] = level1;

    if (row.Field<int>("level_2") != level2)
        row["level_2"] = level2;
    ++level2;
}
```

Comment: Hi NetMage,
Your code work almost perfectly. However, 
I tried to delete 1.0.0 and 1.1.0, the result returned to me is
1.0.0 desc 3
1.0.1 desc 4
1.0.2 desc 5
1.1.0 desc 6
1.1.1 desc 7
1.1.2 desc 8
1.1.3 desc 9
1.1.4 desc 10
1.2.0 desc 11
1.2.1 desc 12
& etc.

Expected output:
1.0.0  desc 3
1.1.0  desc 4
1.1.1  desc 5
1.1.2  desc 6
1.1.3  desc 7
1.2.0  desc 8
1.2.1  desc 9
1.2.2  desc 10
1.2.3  desc 11
1.2.4  desc 12
2.0.0  desc 13
2.1.0  desc 14
2.2.0  desc 15
3.0.0  desc 16
& etc.

Comment: @DominicChan The input is 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.3, 1.20 - how should it decide that 1.1.0, 1.1.1 (change in third level) should map to 1.0.0, 1.1.0 (change in second level)?